# Pocketsphinx recognizer.py does not work

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!
I'm trying to work with pocketsphinx for speech recognition and im currently using this [Tutorial](http://jokla.me/robotics/speech-recognition-ros/)

but i have some troubles:

when i run this command `roslaunch pocketsphinx turtlebot_voice_cmd.launch`

then i got some errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meow/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 177, in <module>
  start = recognizer()
  File "/home/meow/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 73, in __init__
  self.start_recognizer()
  File "/home/meow/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 80, in start_recognizer
  self.pipeline = gst.parse_launch(self.launch_config)
  glib.GError: no element «vader»
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/core.py", line 467, in signal_shutdown
  h()
  File "/home/meow/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 131, in shutdown
  gtk.main_quit()
  RuntimeError: called outside of a mainloop
[recognizer-2] process has died [pid 15287, exit code 1, cmd /home/meow/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py __name:=recognizer __log:=/home/meow/.ros/log/ec640724-686e-11e7-adcd-08d40c6bd6ea/recognizer-2.log].
log file: /home/meow/.ros/log/ec640724-686e-11e7-adcd-08d40c6bd6ea/recognizer-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266363/pocketsphinx-recognizer.py-does-not-work/) by [Martelogie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31126/martelogie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this version instead:
https://github.com/Pankaj-Baranwal/pocketsphinx/
It contains quite many updated features of pocketsphinx. And also supports backward compatibility.
So it will work perfectly! And it is well maintained. So, if you have issues working with it, you can simply open a new issue and the maintainer should respond with a solution soon!
It is well documented too. You can follow the wiki, or the blog posts here:
https://medium.com/@PankajB96/

---

Originally posted by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) with karma: 96 on 2017-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0